# How to put x-axis in order(Month) in R

Tags: r, plot, data-science, data-analysis

I wanna plot with month,but the x-axis is not in order,such as"Apr","Aug","Nov".....
But I want the order on x-axis to be like "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"........

```
#change the format of date
date_month <- format(date_1, "%b")
class(date_month)
[1] "character"

head(date_month)
[1] "Jul" "Jul" "Jul" "Jul" "Jul" "Jul"

plot(table(date_month), xlab = "Month", ylab = "count")
```

[image]

I tried this:

```
x1  <- factor(date_month, levels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",  "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec"))
plot(y ~ x1)
```

and:

```
plot(table(date_month), xlab = "Month", ylab = "count")
axis(date_month,labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",  "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec"))
```

Doesn't work at all.Can someone help me with this?Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in u r code used format to extract months 
                              but use base r function `months` u will 
                              get solution easily

If u use `format` output is like :

```
> head(format(date_month$date, "%b"))
[1] "Jun" "Feb" "Mar" "Oct" "Oct" "Aug"
```

`months` will extract the month name fully like below :

```
> head(months(date_month$date))
[1] "June"     "February" "March"    "October"  "October"  "August"
```

as per u r code do the below :

```
date_month<-months(date_1)
date_month<-factor(date_month,levels=month.name)
```

Now plot and try.

sample code :

```
date_month<-list(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), 
                              as.Date('2018/11/08'), by="day"), 100))

> head(date_month)
        date
1 2018-06-13
2 2018-02-19
3 2018-03-05
4 2018-10-29
5 2018-10-25
6 2018-08-22
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

`month.name` is a built-in 'constant' with all the months' names in long form. To match it to your data use `substr()` and keep only first three characters.

```
date_month <- factor(date_month, levels = substr(month.name, 1, 3))
```

Then plot it as usual.

```
plot(table(date_month), xlab = "Month", ylab = "count")
```

[image]

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
date_1 <- as.Date(sample(0:364, 5e5, replace=TRUE), 
                  origin="2018-01-01")
```